# GAS read argument of program encounter "segmentation fault"

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler, param, debian-based

I'm starting to learn Assembly, and my choosen compiler is GNU AS. The only terrible thing with it is that there's little documentation about AS, it's syntax and it's user guide.

I've coded a hello world program which read a text file (file path is 1st parameter of program) and display its content to stdout. But when I run the program, it's always say "segment fault". Atfer a bit of modifying source code, I found that I encountered problem in reading input argument of the program. If I put file path in source code, there's no problem, but if I read it from input argument, "segmentation fault" occurs.

This is my source code about reading input argument

```
# get file name from argument and put in to ebx
movl 8(%esp), %ebx

# open the file
# movl $path, %ebx
movl $5, %eax
movl $0, %ecx
movl $0666, %edx
int $0x80
```

I've searched a lot of ton about reading input argument in GAS but what I only found is this, a very nice article: [NASM - Linux Getting command line parameters](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/). I copied the code and change a bit to x64 (my machine is kali x64). The interesting thing was that I re-encountered "segmentation fault". What's a sadly day!!!

So if there's anyone who have worked with assemby in Linux, especially with GAS or NASM, please help me solving this problem.

A 1000+ thanks (, if it's possible) for your help

Cong.

update1: this is my full source code

```
.global main
.text
main:
# get file name from parameter and put in to ebx
movl 8(%esp), %ebx
# read path in source code
# movl $path, %ebx

# open the file
# movl $path, %ebx
movl $5, %eax
movl $0, %ecx
movl $0666, %edx
int $0x80

# read the file
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $3, %eax
movl $buf, %ecx
movl $bufSize, %edx
int $0x80

# write to stdout
movl %ebx, %ebp
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $buf, %ecx
int $0x80

# close the file
movl $6, %eax
movl %ebp, %ebx
int $0x80

exit:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80

.data
path:
.asciz "./hello_world.c"
.bss
.equ bufSize, 1024
.lcomm buf, bufSize
```

update 2: my os is x86_64, and that's the root of a lot of problems I encountered when programming assembly in x86_64. with the help of @user35443 and @Jester, I can finally have some workaround: compile to x86 elf file, instead of x64 elf. the source code is the same as above, with a bit of changing main to _start. And because I compile x86 on x86_64, I need something: `apt-get install gcc-multilib`, after that, the compiling is straight forward: `as --32 readfile.s -o readfile.o && ld -m elf_i386 readfile.o -o readfile && ./readfile some_text_file` (ps: I don't know why `gcc -m32 readfile.s` encouter error )

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
# get file name from parameter and put in to ebx
movl 8(%esp), %ebx
# movl $path, %ebx

# open the file
# movl $path, %ebx
movl $5, %eax
movl $0, %ecx
movl $0666, %edx 
int $0x80

# read the file
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $3, %eax
movl $buf, %ecx
movl $bufSize, %edx
int $0x80

# write to stdout
movl %ebx, %ebp
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $buf, %ecx
# size of write is %edx
int $0x80

# close the file
movl $6, %eax
movl %ebp, %ebx
int $0x80

exit:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80

.data
path:
.asciz "./hello_world.c"
.bss
.equ bufSize, 1024
.lcomm buf, bufSize
```

because I focus on x86_64, I will let the question open for a few days, and this is my source code for x84_64 that I can not find root of the problem (maybe I mis-used x86_64 call convention).

```
.global main
.text
main:
# get file name from parameter and put in to rbx
movq 16(%rsp), %rbx
#movq $path, %rbx

# open the file
# movq $path, %rbx
movq $5, %rax
movq $0, %rcx
movq $0666, %rdx 
int $0x80

# read the file
movq %rax, %rbx
movq $3, %rax
movq $buf, %rcx
movq $bufSize, %rdx
int $0x80

# write to stdout
movq %rbx, %rbp
movq $4, %rax
movq $1, %rbx
movq $buf, %rcx
# size of write is %rdx
int $0x80

# close the file
movq $6, %rax
movq %rbp, %rbx
int $0x80

exit:
movq $1, %rax
movq $0, %rbx
int $0x80

.data
path:
.asciz "./hello_world.c"
.bss
.equ bufSize, 1024
.lcomm buf, bufSize
```

Comment: Please post here your full source, especially if you use any preambule that could change the `%esp`.

Comment: I've updated my full source code.

Comment: Are you compiling this as 32-bit or 64-bit executable?

Comment: My command is `gcc readfile.s`, I think that it's 64-bit exe, because I compiled with `gcc -m32 readfile.s`, error occured.

Comment: If I change all registers/operators to x64 (rxx,movq), there's no segmentation fault, but there's nothing outputed

Comment: Try to compile the source with `gcc -m32 file`, then link it with `-m32`. 64-bit syscalls can have different calling conventions, but I would also give a try to replacing just `movl 8(%esp), %ebx` with `movl 16(%rsp), %rbx`.

Comment: can you please compile my source code. I compiled -m32 with failure, my compile said that Error: incorrect register `%rbx' used with `l' suffix with `movl 16(%rsp), %rbx`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It should be `movq` insetad of `movl`. But have you tried compiling bopth source and object file with the `-m32` option?

Comment: as I said above, if I change all registers exx to rxx, movl to movq, no segmentation fault occurs, but nothing is outputed. If I compile with `gcc -m32 readfile.s`, error occur, if I compile with `as --32 readfile.s`, then when I link with `ld -m32 readfile.o -o readfile`, error occur: `ld: unrecognised emulation mode: 32
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 i386linux elf_l1om elf_k1om`

Comment: As I said above, you don't need to change all registers to rxx. What error occurs when you compile with `gcc -m32 readfile.s`?

Comment: If I change only `movl 8(%esp), %ebx` to `movq 16(%rsp), %rbx`, no segmentation fault, and nothing outputed.

If I `gcc -m32 readfile.s`, with origin exx, movl code:
`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or dir
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so when search for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipp incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a when search for -lgcc
`

Comment: You don't have the 32 bit compiler support packages installed. On debian based systems that would be `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: thank @user35443 and @Jester, I can finally run with 32 bit elf
After installing `apt-get install gcc-multilib`, I compile with original code `as --32 readfile.s -o readfile.o && ld -m elf_i386 reafile.o -o readfile && ./readfile some_text_file`
This make me very happy that my code is true with 32-bit exe, but does anyone know why I can not get argument with 64-bit exe? I've searched a lot, and all every thing point that maybe I mis-used x86_64 call convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a 64 bit port of the code:

```
.global main
.text
main:
push %rbx           # save rbx
# get file name from parameter and put in to rdi
# argv in rsi
# open the file
movq 8(%rsi), %rdi  # path
movl $0, %esi       # flags
movl $0666, %edx    # mode
movl $2, %eax       # SYS_OPEN
syscall
movl %eax, %ebx     # save fd

# read the file
movl %eax, %edi     # fd
leaq buf, %rsi      # buf
movl $bufSize, %edx # count
movl $0, %eax       # SYS_READ
syscall

# write to stdout
movl $1, %edi       # stdout
leaq buf, %rsi      # buf
movl %eax, %edx     # count
movl $1, %eax       # SYS_WRITE

syscall

# close the file
movl %ebx, %esi     # fd
movl $3, %eax       # SYS_CLOSE
syscall

exit:
xor %eax, %eax      # return 0
pop %rbx            # restore rbx
ret

.data
path:
.asciz "./hello_world.c"
.bss
.equ bufSize, 1024
.lcomm buf, bufSize
```

Note, it is not a good idea to use raw system calls from a program that's using libc. It's particularly bad to use the exit system call because that leaves no chance for the c library to shut down. I have removed the exit system call, but left the others intact. The system call numbers and calling convention is different for 64 bit. You can get a quick overview at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) or read the ABI docs for the full picture.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jester. You've saved my life. I'm completely newbie in assembly programming, there're too many kind of compiler, syntax, and thing to learn. You're my God :)

Comment: I've one more question: why does argv[0] stored under 8(%rsi), as far as I know about ELF format, argv[0] should be stored in 8(%rsp). Is it any system function which call main entry of ELF that make argv[0] appear in main entry under 8(%rsi)?

Comment: Yes, the C library. This code is using `main` entry point which is called by the C library which contains the real entry point. `main` already gets the arguments as per the C calling convention.

Comment: Can I disable this? Do you have any documentation about assembly programming in x64 machine? There's too many tutorials, too many hidden thing that I don't know which is good starting point.